# Install pkg with Conda: windows error(2,'The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: conda, windows-error-reporting, holoviews

On Windows 7 64-bit, I'm trying to install Holoview with Conda (Python 2.7) as recommended with this prompt:

```
conda install -c ioam holoviews bokeh
```

However, I keep on receiving the following message.

```
INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
prefix: 'C:\Users\Nish7\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2', env_name: 'None', mo
de: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
prefix: 'C:\Users\Nish7\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2', env_name: 'None', mo
de: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing
package 'defaults::qt-5.6.2-vc9_6'.
WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified')
Attempting to roll back.

INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
prefix: 'C:\Users\Nish7\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2', env_name: 'None', mo
de: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
INFO menuinst_win32:__init__(182): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}',
prefix: 'C:\Users\Nish7\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2', env_name: 'None', mo
de: 'user', used_mode: 'user'

WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified')
```

What should I do before attempting to install the package?

Comment: Try to install the package in an existing environment or create an environment for it. To list the environments run `conda env list`. To install on an environment run `conda install -n=environmentname ioam holoviews bokeh`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell; could be some problem with a particular conda file for your system, or could be something simple like you running out of disk space for downloads or installations.  In any case, qt isn't used directly by holoviews, only as a dependency of matplotlib, so there may be a way to force it to install anyway if qt is really the only problem.